# How to exclude a subdirectory from WP search that has no category or page/post ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I need to exclude a folder from the built-in WP search. We have a folder built dynamically from a plugin, and need it to be excluded - so if the URL is:

www.acme.com/blog/material

I need everything under "material" excluded. The catch is there is not a category or ID associated with the "material" folder, so I somehow need to refer to it by the URL string. So basically, don't return anything with that URL of any subfolder of the URL.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How does your current code look like?

Comment: No code yet, I was looking around and found examples that could be dropped into the functions.php file, like:
  function SearchFilter($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
  $query->set('post_type', 'post');
  }
  return $query;

  }

  add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

but nothing that shows how to refer to a string or url.